# SVNKIT: How can I retrieve a diff of an entire check-in just by providing the check-in's number?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

Would anybody know how can I get from svnkit a diff of all changes in a single revision just by supplying that single revision number?

```
final SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory = new SvnOperationFactory();
try {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final SvnDiffGenerator diffGenerator = new SvnDiffGenerator();
    diffGenerator.setBasePath(new File(MAIN_PATH, RELEASE_VER_PATH));
    final SvnDiff diff = svnOperationFactory.createDiff();
    diff.setSource(SvnTarget.fromURL(svnurl), SVNRevision.create(14000), SVNRevision.create(14045));                        diff.setDiffGenerator(diffGenerator);
    diff.setOutput(System.out);
    diff.run();
} finally {
    svnOperationFactory.dispose();
}
```

The problem is that all I know, is the value of 14045. I have no way of knowing the 14000.
Is there a different way I can retrieve a diff of an entire check-in just by providing the check-in's number?